# Get Injected Object in ASP.NET vNext filter

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create my custom authorize attribute, but in asp.net vnext using the default dependency injection framework I don't how to get the injected object. I need to get the injected object in the default ctor.

```
   public  class CustomAttribute
{

   private IDb _db;

   public CustomAttribute()
   {
       _db = null; // get injected object
   }

   public CustomAttribute(IDb db)
   {
       _db = db;
   }

   // apply all authentication logic
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceFilterAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Filters/ServiceFilterAttribute.cs) for this purpose. The service filter attribute lets the DI system take care of instantiating and maintaining the lifetime of the filter `CustomAuthorizeFilter` and its any required services.

Example:

```
// register with DI
services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddTransient<CustomAuthorizeFilter>();

//------------------

public class CustomAuthorizeFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public CustomAuthorizeFilter(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationContext context)
    {
        //do something here    
    }
}

//------------------

[ServiceFilter(typeof(CustomAuthorizeFilter))]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be add as a singleton or can be added using transientent services.addtransient

Comment: @Son_of_Sam: Sure, it can be a transient too...it just depends on the scenario that you are implementing...